# I want to start a ngrok server and log everything to a file and to the terminal but it isnt working

Tags: python, logging, tcp, ngrok, pyngrok

Code:

```py
from pyngrok import ngrok

public_url = ngrok.connect(
    log_stdout=True, log_file="ngrok.log", log_format="json", log_level="debug", proto="tcp", addr="8080"
)
print(public_url)
while True:
    pass
```

I found this on the internet but it aint working, well its starting the server but its not logging anything, how do i make it log things?

thanks

Comment: Curious where you found this. `pyngrok`'s `connect()` does take `kwargs`, but I'm not sure passing those `log_` args would actually do anything, and in fact `pyngrok` cannot log to a file, as the wrapper relies on console log output for its own execution.

Might I suggest using the `log_event_callback` instead? I think that could possibly work for what you're trying to do, and it's documented [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#event-logs).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that approach but in general, you probably want to do it a little bit differently. Check out the local ngrok API - https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-agent/api#list-captured-requests - which will let you capture all the requests in JSON for logging, replay, or whatever.

~ an ngrok employee